# jsHint - webpack warning Bad option: 'force'. @ line 0 char 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jshint

I have a problem regarding jsHint with webpack.
I get this warning in every file:

```
WARNING in ./app/app.component.js
jshint results in errors
  Bad option: 'force'. @ line 0 char 0
```

My jsHint options:

```
var options = {
    quotmark: 'single',
    eqeqeq: true,
    strict: false,
    globals: {
        define: false,
        module: false,
        angular: false,
        app: false,
        Chart: false,
    }
};

module.exports = options;
```

Versions

- "jshint": "^2.9.2",
- "jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
- "webpack": "^1.13.0",

What does it mean and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove in your jsHint configuration the `force` option. Just setting it to false won't do. Also check your external and default loaded configuration files for that option.

I had this option enabled too, but it seems not to be valid anymore with newer versions of jsHint.